# Terminate Spring Kafka transaction if Kafka server is unavailable

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In our project, we need to periodically fetch data from the 3rd party by many threads and to push this data to the Kafka then. And if Kafka server is not available at the moment, the flow should be terminated, the fetched data should be lost and re-fetched during the next scheduled execution. Also, there's a need to use transaction management, because we need to send the batch of messages to Kafka to different topics. And if one message is not sent, all others should be rolled back.

We've been experiencing an issue with terminating execution if Kafka Server is not available. When transaction management is disabled, everything works fine and we're getting

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

But with transaction management enabled, Kafka producer tries to reach the server infinitely and all threads that initiate pushing messages to Kafka sticking. We've tried different settings to make it fail after some time of unavailability, but it didn't help.
Setting `spring.kafka.producer.retries: 0` or `spring.kafka.producer.acks: 0` causes (not full stacktrace):

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Must set retries to non-zero when using the idempotent producer.

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Must set acks to all in order to use the idempotent producer. Otherwise we cannot guarantee idempotence.
```

Is there some combination of settings that make Kafka Producer fail after some timeout when Kafka server is not available and the transaction management is enabled? And is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

Spring-Kafka uses `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` to seek to the failed offset and try again - This will keep looping until the offset is processed correctly. This is default behaviour. You will rollback if the transaction fail which depends on the `rollbackFor` property on `@Transactional`.

You got a special case where it will rollback if the Kafka server is unavailable. You can create your own processor by implementing `AfterRollbackProcessor`. You will need to discern regular rollbacks from rollbacks due to connection timeout.

**Edit:**
You can also define property `noRollbackFor` on `@Transactional` to exclude `TimeoutException` and let this exception reach the `Container`. You can create custom ExceptionHandler and use `setErrorHandler(..)` on the container. You can read about the container error handlers [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_consumer_aware_container_error_handlers)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but both ways didn't work for me.
I've tried to debug and found out that `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` is never executed in my case. Also, I've noticed that `org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor#process` is called only in `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`, but my application is the message Producer, not the Consumer.
Also, I actually need `TimeoutException` to be thrown and when transaction management is enabled it is never thrown and this is my problem :)

Comment: I took a second look at your problem. I was able to reproduce the problem you describe. I looked at `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender` - I cannot spot any properties to adjust this behaviour. I never encountered this behaviour before. Is your Kafka broker down from the beginning? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5415 looks similar to your problem.

Comment: It's a bug in the kafka client (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226546/defaultkafkaproducerfactory-with-transactionidprefix-endless-waits-when-bootstra/48230110#48230110)). It will be fixed in kafka-clients 2.0.0 - see [KAFKA-6446](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6446).

Comment: @GaryRussell thank you! currently, we're using spring kafka 2.1.6.RELEASE which uses kafka-clients 1.0.1. I'll think about a workaround for now, but I would really appreciate if you could tell the planned date for kafka-clients 2.0.0 to be released.

Comment: Sorry, I am not part of the kafka team (only spring-kafka, which uses the kafka-clients jar). Their [release plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=80448820) says June 26. I have tested a version of spring-kafka 2.2 against their 2.0.0.rc1 branch; so I am awaiting their release in order to release the 2.2.0.M1 milestone.